# Need an Api or webhook for youtube streaming notification

Tags: youtube-api, streaming, live

I need to find an Api/webhook, source code for youtube. Specifically, that Api/webhook will send me a notification only when a specific youtuber makes a direct live streaming transmission.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer with this link: [Is there a way to get notifications from YouTube API when broadcaster is live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46558476/is-there-a-way-to-get-notifications-from-youtube-api-when-broadcaster-is-live). It stated that it requires a websocket connection with your API endpoint by using ws:// protocole at some point. Websocket listen to a server, and enable your browser to handle it's changes like events. So it's exacly what u need for notifications.

Also, you may use the `GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts` endpoint which returns a list of YouTube broadcasts that match the API request parameters.

> However, getting a notification will require some work. It will probably require polling the endpoint for changes to determine if a new broadcast has been started. I'm not aware of a PUSH API from YouTube to send a request to an endpoint of your choice to create a notification.
>
> More info in the [YouTube docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list).